# want to import a api into google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript

So i have copied an working code and try to change it to the api i wanted to import

like this

```
function fetchdata_Coinswap() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.coin-swap.net/market/summary');
    var json=response.getContentText();
    var data=JSON.parse(json);  
    var output= new Array()
    var i= 0
    var currency = '';
    for (currency in data['exchange']) {
        output[i]= ['Coinswap',currency ,data['exchange'][currency]['lastprice'],data['exchange'][currency]['symbol']];
        i=i+1;
    }
    ss.getRange('Sheet1!A14:D'+(i+13)).setValues(output)
    return                    
}
```

The problem i have now is that it says,

> ```
> Incorrect range height, was 0 but should be 2 (line 63, file "Code")
> ```

i have tried to change the range but everytime i get that the range is incoorect. I think also that i did something wrong in the output, that the range error comes. Does someone can give me a little help. im tottaly new to this, thanks in advance

Comment: I have do some research on it, and i know at this moment that the error means that its not collecting any data in the range, i have to find a way to extract the data from the json into the spreadsheet.

Comment: i'm now testing a new script to run, just waiting for an update in the shee. when its confirmed i shall answer it here